# Calcular dimensiones de una imagen usando jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Quisiera saber como calcular el tamaño (ancho y altura) de varias imágenes usando jquery, quisiera hacer validaciones al obtener dichos tamaños.
Este es el script que tengo hasta.

```
/*jQuery*/
var ancho;
var alto;
$("img").each(function(){
  ancho = $(this).width();
  alto = $(this).height();

  if(ancho < alto)
    console.log("Es más ancha");
  else if(ancho > alto)
    console.log("Es más alto");
  else
    console.log("Es una imagen cuadrada");
});
```

Este es el código en HTML

```
<!--HTML-->
<img src="imagen1.jpg">
<img src="imagen2.jpg">
<img src="imagen3.jpg">
```

Comment: Pero ¿Qué te esta fallando del código? o ¿Cual es tú problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No veo problema con tu código. Lo único que se me ocurre es que estés intentando medir las imágenes antes de que hayan terminado de cargar.

Para manejar eso puedes ejecutar la medición cuando terminen de cargar utilizando el evento `load`. **Peeero...** como puede darse el caso de que la imagen cargue antes de que declares el listener sobre el evento, puedes añadir además una comprobación sobre la propiedad `complete` de la imagen, forzándola a que emita un evento `load` que jQuery pueda detectar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="cuadrado" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAASElEQVR42u3PQREAMAgAoNlhtewfwRiawa8HDYhf2e+AEBERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERHZGA3lchHmrzGHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">


<img id="vertical" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAA8CAYAAAAUufjgAAAAR0lEQVR42u3OAQ0AMAgAoNvhMexfyRhawzlIQOSvfouFoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKDgveAAMq6BJbaAYxwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">

<img id="horizontal" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAAoCAYAAACiu5n/AAAARUlEQVR42u3PMQEAMAgAoNlht/2bGUNb+AgNiMrf75AQFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhbeNfkSU+klXpjsAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("img").one("load", function() {
  var ancho = $(this).width(),
  alto = $(this).height();

  if(ancho > alto)
    console.log(this.id,"Es más ancha");
  else if(ancho < alto)
    console.log(this.id,"Es más alto");
  else
    console.log(this.id,"Es una imagen cuadrada");
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) {
    $(this).load();
  } 
});
 

});
</script>
```